# Typing and derivating unevaluated sums

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

First I would like to get the output of

```
F[x_, y_, k_] := Sum[x^(m - n)*y^m, {n, 0, k}, {m, n, k - 1}]
```

as an unevaluated (symbolic) sum. Then, derivate F

```
D[F[x, y, k], x]
```

and also get the derivative as an unevaluated sum. ¿Is it possible?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive):

```
F[x_, y_, k_] := Inactive[Sum][x^(m - n)*y^m, {n, 0, k}, {m, n, k - 1}]
```

Differentiate:

```
D[F[x,y,k], x]
```

> Inactive[Sum][(m x^(-1 + m - n) - n x^(-1 + m - n)) y^m, {n, 0, k}, {m, 
>     n, -1 + k}]

In Mathematica, the above is rendered as:

[image]